# Prove that interchanging the $ij$-entries of $n \times n$ matrix will not change the result(eigenvalues).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove that interchanging the entries of an $n \times n$ matrix will not change the result.But I don't know how. Please help!

Comment: they have the same characteristic polynomial, and hence the same eigenvalues

Comment: https://yutsumura.com/eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-and-its-transpose-are-the-same/

Comment: @SakethMalyala tranpose of a matrix is transposing a row(column) to column(row). how about rearranging each entries randomly does it also holds?. Im confused with this.

Comment: @ElNumeral - no, it does not hold, $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ do not have the same eigenvalues. I can't imagine why one would even suspect that it would hold.

Comment: @PaulSinclair that's why I'm so confused. How to use the concept of $A$  and $A^T$ have the same characteristic polynomial?

Comment: The eigenvalues are the zeros of the characteristic polynomial. If two matrices both have the same characteristic polynomial, then of course they have the same eigenvalues. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - A)$. Because $(\lambda I - A)^T = \lambda I - A^T$ and $\det M = \det M^T$, $A$ and $A^T$ must have the same characteristic polynomial. Properly explaining why the determinant is unaffected by transposing is too deep for a comment. Like the fact that determinants commute with multiplication, I advise just accepting it for now.